# Javascript - replace all lines with fewer than X characters

Tags: javascript, regex, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a Javascript bookmarklet that will:

- look at the contents of a form field (of class "mceContentBody"),
- find all paragraph tags in which the contents inside the tag are less
  than 50 characters, and
- add "strong" tags inside.

So
    `<p>This is less than 50 chars</p>`
would become
    `<p><strong>This is less than 50 chars</strong></p>`

but
    `<p>This is a very long line that is more than 50 characters so it will remain untouched.</p>`

Here is what I have right now, but when I run it, it makes the entire contents of the form field bold.

I am sure I have botched something with the regex. What am I missing?

```
javascript:var x = window.frames[1].document.getElementsByClassName("mceContentBody")[0].innerHTML;

x=x.replace(/(<p.*?>([A-Za-z ]{0,50})<\/p>)/g, "<p><strong>$1</strong></p>");

window.frames[1].document.getElementsByClassName("mceContentBody")[0].innerHTML=x;empty();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Don't parse html with regex, just use the polished html parser at hand:

```
function replaceContents( contents ) {
var div = document.createElement("div"),
    paragraphs, i, l, paragraph, text,
    textProp = "textContent" in div ? "textContent" : "innerText";

div.innerHTML = contents;

paragraphs = div.getElementsByTagName("p");
l = paragraphs.length;

    for( i = 0; i < l; ++i ) {
    paragraph = paragraphs[i];
    text = paragraph[textProp];

        if( text.length > 0 && text.length < 50 ) {
        paragraph.innerHTML = "<strong>"+text+"</strong>";
        }
    }

return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Example use here: http://jsfiddle.net/wUfRQ/

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to this so you match everything but the end of the P opening tag it should be something like the following (or [see this regex test](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%28%3Cp%5B%5E%3E%5D%2a%3E%28%5BA-Za-z%20%5D%7B0,50%7D%29%3C%5C/p%3E%29&input=%3Cform%3E%3Cp%3EThis%20is%20my%20form%20it%20has%20a%20lot%20of%20words%20in%20this%20paragraph%20because%20it%20is%20too%20cool%20for%20school.%20This%20is%20my%20form%20it%20has%20a%20lot%20of%20words%20in%20this%20paragraph%20because%20it%20is%20too%20cool%20for%20school.%20This%20is%20my%20form%20it%20has%20a%20lot%20of%20words%20in%20this%20paragraph%20because%20it%20is%20too%20cool%20for%20school.%20This%20is%20my%20form%20it%20has%20a%20lot%20of%20words%20in%20this%20paragraph%20because%20it%20is%20too%20cool%20for%20school.%3C/p%3E%3Cp%3EShort%3C/p%3E%3C/form%3E)):

```
x=x.replace(/(<p[^>]*?>([A-Za-z ]{0,50})<\/p>)/g, "<p><strong>$1</strong></p>");
```

The issue here is that you're matching too much (see [this regex test](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%28%3Cp.%2a%3E%28%5BA-Za-z%20%5D%7B0,50%7D%29%3C%5C/p%3E%29&input=%3Cform%3E%3Cp%3EThis%20is%20my%20form%20it%20has%20a%20lot%20of%20words%20in%20this%20paragraph%20because%20it%20is%20too%20cool%20for%20school.%20This%20is%20my%20form%20it%20has%20a%20lot%20of%20words%20in%20this%20paragraph%20because%20it%20is%20too%20cool%20for%20school.%20This%20is%20my%20form%20it%20has%20a%20lot%20of%20words%20in%20this%20paragraph%20because%20it%20is%20too%20cool%20for%20school.%20This%20is%20my%20form%20it%20has%20a%20lot%20of%20words%20in%20this%20paragraph%20because%20it%20is%20too%20cool%20for%20school.%3C/p%3E%3Cp%3EShort%3C/p%3E%3C/form%3E))..  Here's a good sample HTML that I'm guessing is like the one you're having an issue with.

```
<form><p>This is my form it has a lot of words in this paragraph because it is too cool for school. This is my form it has a lot of words in this paragraph because it is too cool for school. This is my form it has a lot of words in this paragraph because it is too cool for school. This is my form it has a lot of words in this paragraph because it is too cool for school.</p><p>Short</p></form>
```

Note: this will have some misses. If for some reason there is a ">" character in your P opening tag.  I made assumptions that that wasn't the case as that is rather rare unless JavaScript is inlined.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code to this (reasons are in the comment block):

```
var x = window.frames[1].document.getElementsByClassName("mceContentBody")[0].innerHTML;
/*
    Changed: <p.*?>
    To: <p[^>]*>
    Because: "." will include ">". By making a negated character class, we are ensuring that the regex will find the closing ">".

    Changed: [A-Za-z ]{0,50}
    To: [^<]{1,50}
    Because: Paragraph elements can contain other characters than letters and spaces (including your example paragraph to be captured.
             Properly formated HTML should never have a "<" character in the innerHTML of a paragraph element.
             Made the minimum "1" because there's no point to putting an empty strong element inside an empty paragraph element.

        Removed outer capturing block as it was not being used.

*/
x = x.replace(/<p[^>]*>([^<]{1,50})<\/p>/g, "<p><strong>$1</strong></p>");
window.frames[1].document.getElementsByClassName("mceContentBody")[0].innerHTML = x;
empty();
```

The only problem JSLint has with this is that the use of the negating character class is considered "insecure" because of the possibility of capturing Unicode characters. However, as you are not using this for an input field, that should be a non-issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Unfortunately I don't have enough Reputation to upvote your response, but this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Your outer parentheses capture the entire match, so `$1` is not want you want. Use `$2` instead.

Or remove the outer parentheses.